# How to using sndPlaySound function to play "empty the recycle bin" sound by using It's alias?

Tags: c#, winapi, system-sounds

For some reasons, I want to play a system sound which is named "EmptyRecycleBin" in my program when a file has been deleted.

So I wrote these code:

**Code1**

```
[DllImport("winmm.dll", EntryPoint = "sndPlaySound")]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
private static extern Boolean SndPlaySound(String pszSound, Int32 fuSound);
private const Int32 SND_SYSTEM = 0x00200000;

SndPlaySound("EmptyRecycleBin", SND_SYSTEM );  //The sound that was played is wrong, but I don't know why……
```

<del>sndPlaySound function executes successfully, but unfortunately, the sound that was played is "Beep".</del>

According to @AlexK. 's explain, sndPlaySound function can't identify the alias "EmptyRecycleBin".

In this case, I have to do this in another way:

**Code2**

```
 var sound = new SoundPlayer(Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(@"AppEvents\Schemes\Apps\Explorer\EmptyRecycleBin\.Current", false).GetValue(null) as String);
 sound.PlaySync();
```

It's all ok, but I still want to know that if it's possible to make Code1 work by using any other alias?

My system is windows 10, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Its not playing the wrong sound its playing the default sound as it can't locate EmptyRecycleBin (see snd_nodefault).  FWIW this code does not work for me either, it does with some other monikers like "DeviceConnect".  Process monitor shows that it does not look in that particular \Explorer subkey.

Comment: @AlexK. Thanks a lot, I will modify my question.

Comment: `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\AppEvents\Schemes\Apps\.Default` registry key I think. Using SND_NODEFAULT is important so you won't play a sound that the user does not want to hear.  This is configured by the user through Control Panel > Sounds > Sounds tab.  I can't find the equivalent of "EmptyRecycleBin" back in the list, looks like an oversight.

Comment: As documented, ["`sndPlaySound` offers a subset of the functionality of the `PlaySound` function"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd798676(v=vs.85).aspx). As [documented](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd743680(v=vs.85).aspx), when using a system sound alias with `PlaySound`, it must be one one of the: `SystemAsterisk`, `SystemDefault`, `SystemExclamation`, `SystemExit`, `SystemHand`, `SystemQuestion`, `SystemStart`, `SystemWelcome`.

Comment: Thats true for SND_ALIAS_ID but any valid string is ok with SND_ALIAS which is how sndPlaySound behaves.